# CSS and different environments

Tags: css, accessibility

What is the best approach to have a different CSS dependent if the person is disabled?

For example larger text, different colours etc.?

Comment: The best approach is not need different CSS for those users.

Comment: @robertc : why? Alternative looks and feels, such as high-contrast, are one of the reasons they created CSS in the first place.

Comment: @WyattBarnett How will the users who need high contrast find the options for enabling the feature?

Comment: Can they get the brower to tell the server that that require a page of high contrast? BTW lots of males are colour blind

Comment: @marc - i know the recommendation but what is the best and easiest why to implement if?

Comment: A site written using best practices and web standards is 99% ready for use with a range of accessibility devices and software. While things like high contrast and larger fonts sizes are great features, they are features that are often already implemented in the OS/browser, so no need to write a custom atypical solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Canadian National Institute for the Blind site: http://www.cnib.ca/en/

They have implemented some good features, such as

1. changing contrast
2. changing text size
3. skip to content
4. tables for tabular data only

For the most part, this is just switching out stylesheets as needed.

If you do this, you should probably use cookies to maintain preferences across the site.

Importantly, you should place the links for these options are the top of the page, where they will be easily accessible, both to view and through the tab structure.

Comment: Thank you. but how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery styleswitcher with cookies to keep the users' preferences here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/ and a method for implementing one in an accessible way here: http://www.alistapart.com/d/bodyswitchers/iotbs.html

However, you should be making sure that your standard site colours, font size, etc are meeting a basic level of accessibility to begin with. WCAG2 Level A at a minimum, and high-contrast/text-size etc as an optional extra. If users are having trouble perceiving your site to begin with, finding and using the styleswitcher is just another difficult task for them before they can get to your content.